# Having trouble with reading from file

Tags: c++, file, getline

Okay, so i am supposed to read an entire line of a file and then go through and individually separate each piece into the correct grouping.  Here is the code that i have written so far.

```
while(!inFile.getline(largeString, LINE_SIZE, '\n').eof() && count < TEAMS)
    {
        next = 0;
        next = buildStruct(largeString, smallString, next);
        strcpy(stats[count].name, smallString);
        cout << stats[count].name << endl;
        next = buildStruct(largeString, smallString, next);
        stats[count].wins = atoi(smallString);
        cout << stats[count].wins << endl;
        next = buildStruct(largeString, smallString, next);
        stats[count].losses = atoi(smallString);
        cout << stats[count].losses << endl;
        next = buildStruct(largeString, smallString, next);
        stats[count].overtime_losses = atoi(smallString);
        cout << stats[count].overtime_losses << endl;
        count++;
    }
```

and here is the contents of my file

```
 Brookings  12   24    7

   Aberdeen     22    16 2

 Austin    28   11     1

  Bismark   24   13      4

    Minot  18    21     3
```

This is what i am getting from the compiler

```
Brookings
12
24
7

0
0
0
Aberdeen
22
16
2
```

i dont know where the zeros are coming from... please help

Comment: Your text file have a blank newline after each line with data. You don't seem to be avoiding lines which are blank

Comment: Look into [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream), you'll love it.

Answer (score 0):

Before going with the processing, check whether `largeString` is empty.

```
while(!inFile.getline(largeString, LINE_SIZE, '\n').eof() && count < TEAMS)    
{
if(largeString && largeString[0] != '\0')
{
next = 0;
...
...
}
}
```

As Beta, suggested you should definitely look into stringstreams.